# Hand-shaking lemma

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to understand the statement of the hand-shaking lemma: "A finite graph G has an even number of vertices with odd degree". And the formula is $\sum_{x \in V(G)}deg(x) = 2 |E| $. I don't understand how this formula says that we have an even number of vertices with odd degree, can someone help me clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The formula implies that the sum of all degrees is even (namely $2|E|$).

The sum of one odd number is odd, the sum of two odd numbers is even (!), the sum of three odd numbers is odd again (it's even plus odd, by the case of 2 etc), the sum of 4 odd numbers is even (we can group them 2 by 2, so we have a number of even sums...), etc. Adding even degrees to a sum does not change the parity. So an odd number of odd degrees sums to an odd number, an even number of odd degrees sums to an even number.

So we must have an even number of odd degrees (to make the sum even).

You could work mod 2 if you know that trick, as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note that $\sum_{x \in V} d(x)$ can also be written as:

$$\sum_{x \in V \mid d(x) \text{ is even}} d(x) + \sum_{x \in V \mid d(x) \text{ is odd}} d(x)$$

Then, work modulo $2$.